# Advanced Custom Fields - Check multiple Empty Fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a Directory in Wordpress, and using Advanced Custom Fields for the client to populate the directory entries. One of the sections is for Social Media icons.

Using the following code, I can check to see if any of the three fields (twitter / facebook / linked-in) is empty, and if empty to not show an icon:

```
<li><?php if(get_field('twitter') != ""): ?><a href="<?php the_field('twitter'); ?>" class="twitter">Twitter<span></span></a></li>
<?php else: ?><?php endif; ?> 
<li><?php if(get_field('facebook') != ""): ?><a href="<?php the_field('facebook'); ?>" class="facebook">Facebook<span></span></a></li>
<?php else: ?><?php endif; ?>
<li><?php if(get_field('linked_in') != ""): ?><a href="<?php the_field('linked_in'); ?>" class="linked">Linked In<span></span></a></li>
<?php else: ?><?php endif; ?>
```

I need help in working how to check to see if all 3 fields are empty to show additional text. (E.g There are no social icons to display).

I currently have:

```
<?php if(get_field('linked_in') && get_field('twitter') && get_field('facebook') != ""): ?>
<span class="small">There are no Social Media links to display</span><?php endif; ?>
```

However, using this code shows nothing when all 3 fields are empty - but shows the text 'There are no social...' when all 3 fields **have** values instead!

I'd be very appreciative if anyone can send me in the right direction on this one. I'm pretty much still a newbie, but trying hard to learn so please be gentle!

Answer (score 1):

Note that [`get_field`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/get_field/) returns `false` and **not** an empty string when no value is found. It's not written in the docs there but you can try a `var_dump` on an empty `get_field` item to confirm.

So you should check them against `false`. I've broken down each condition on its own line for the sake of simplicity:

```
<?php 
if(
    ( false === get_field('linked_in') ) && #no linked_in value
    ( false === get_field('twitter') ) && #no twitter value
    ( false === get_field('facebook') )  #no facebook value
  ): 
?>
<span class="small">There are no Social Media links to display</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Test for return value of `get_field` on an item that does not exist:

```
var_dump( get_field('dummy_string',232) );
// results: bool(false)
```

Comment: $var = false; var_dump( empty($var) ); // true

Comment: $var = ''; var_dump( empty($var) ); // true

Comment: Yep, but why call another function when we can compare against `false` directly?

Comment: `empty()` will also return `true` for integer `0`, float `0.0` and string `0`, which could potentially be a saved post meta value.

Comment: Hi rrikesh. Thanks so much for the help; it's greatly appreciated. However, when I said I'm 'pretty much a newbie' I wasn't exaggerating! I'm not sure what I need to do with the var_dump - and where exactly to put it. If you can help further that'd be fantastic - but no worries if not.

Comment: [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is just a function that gives you the content of a variable. It is useful when you want to find what is the content of that variable especially if it is an array or an object. But here, I mentionned `var_dump` for explanatory purposes only. You could read about it and learn to use it. There's also [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) which does a somehow similar job.

Comment: I must agree with rrikesh. Comparison against `false` is more all-purpose although don't required in given question.

Answer (score 0):

Your if-statement wont work the way you want it.

**Change this part of the code**

```
if(get_field('linked_in') && get_field('twitter') && get_field('facebook') != "")
```

**Into**

```
if(empty(get_field('linked_in')) && empty(get_field('twitter')) && empty(get_field('facebook')))
```

This way all three fields will be checked whether they are empty or not.

Comment: Hi Mike. Many thanks for your help, it's much appreciated - but unfortunately I'm getting this error when using that code: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Answer (score 0):

As this is still coming up pretty high in Google results, I thought I'd add the alternative answer that helped for me. Not sure if ACF have updated their coding since this was answered, but only the following worked for me:

```
<?php
     if(
         ( !get_field('linked_in') ) && #no linked_in value
         ( !get_field('twitter') ) && #no twitter value
         ( !get_field('facebook') ) &&  #no facebook value
     ): 
?>
   <p>There are no Social Media links to display </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```